# How do I pass arguments containing special characters to a bash script?

Tags: bash, special-characters

Normally I can run a command to run a sql script via the commandline in the following manner in my server:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ sudo mysql -h BLAHBLAHBLAH.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u user -p'aaaaa:b>c[d{e]ff=|ggggggggg^$*' adi_chf_db < ./test.sql
```

So I wanted to make this simple and have a bash script run it for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

sql_cmd_to_run="sudo mysql -h BLAHBLAHBLAH.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u user -p\'aaaaa:b>c[d{e]ff=|ggggggggg^$*\' test_database < ./test.sql"
ssh -t test_server "${sql_cmd_to_run}"
```

My result is the following:

```
bash: ggggggggg^': command not found
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'XX.XX.XX.XXX' (using password: YES)
Connection to XX.XX.XX.XXX closed.
```

I also understand that there are some special characters in bash so I tried the following as well (by putting \ before the special characters):

```
#!/bin/bash

sql_cmd_to_run="sudo mysql -h BLAHBLAHBLAH.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u user -p\'aaaaa:b\>c\[d\{e\]ff=\|ggggggggg\^$\*\' test_database < ./test.sql"
ssh -t test_server "${sql_cmd_to_run}"
```

Which the output is:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'XX.XX.XX.XXX' (using password: YES)
Connection to XX.XX.XX.XXX closed.
```

(I've obscured some of the values, obviously for some security reasons.)

Comment: please don't tag spam. It inserts your question into search results where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to do shell quoting by hand: Let the shell do it for you.

So, if you have a working local command:

```
sudo mysql -h BLAHBLAHBLAH.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u user -p'aaaaa:b>c[d{e]ff=|ggggggggg^$*' adi_chf_db < ./test.sql
```

...then encapsulate it in a function, by adding a `mycmd() {` line before and a `}` line after:

```
mycmd() {
  sudo mysql -h BLAHBLAHBLAH.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u user -p'aaaaa:b>c[d{e]ff=|ggggggggg^$*' adi_chf_db < ./test.sql
}
```

...and tell the shell to serialize that function into your ssh session:

```
ssh test_server "$(declare -f mycmd); mycmd"
```

Comment: Hey that's a neat trick :) , it saves me the time of having to deal with those pesky special characters haha.